# Android : Add 3D border with around an view

Tags: android, 3d, border

I would like to create the same border of this view as example :

[image: Example1]

or like this progressBar:

[image]

In this example, we can see that the border is not the same all around the view. How can i create this using an xml drawable file ?

Comment: Any idea about this?